# In tomcat cluster when the session synchronization is triggered?

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, myfaces

Consider the scenario

1. I have put an object on one instance of a tomcat cluster, Will i get the object on the other node immediately?
2. If change one property of that object on node2, will it be available on node1 immediately?

I am getting a problem regarding this in a JSF application my @SessionScoped beans are not synchronizing between nodes. This bean implements Serializable interface. And `<distributable />` element is defined in web.xml.